# Eclipse adiciona tag ao código ao tentar resolver conflitos

Tags: php, git, eclipse, merge

Galera, a situação a seguir serve apenas para exemplificar o que acontece quando eu tento resolver um conflito pelo Eclipse. Eu sei como resolver um conflito, o problema é que após resolvê-lo essa tags continuam presentes. Conflitos sempre vão existir, não tenho como evitá-los no meu projeto, e eles estão aí para serem resolvidos, e eu sei como resolvê-los. Pois bem, seguem os passos que eu sigo:

Ao realizar um merge pelo Eclipse, do master para o branch que estou trabalhando, me deparo com um conflito.

1. Faço um synchronize
2. Seleciono o arquivo com conflito
3. Botão direito, Merge Tool
4. Não altero nada (Embora às vezes altero e dá a mesma coisa)
5. Botão direito no arquivo novamente
6. Add to index.

Quando abro o arquivo verifico que o Eclipse salvou ele com essa tags da imagem abaixo.

[image: tag que inviabilizam o codigo]

O estranho é que o Merge Tool oferece a opção de 3 editores quando ele mostra a comparação. Se eu seleciono o Text Editor o conflito é resolvido sem esse problema, se eu deixo o padrão (default) acontece o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é o Eclipse que faz isso, é o próprio `git` (os menus do Eclipse só chamam os comandos do git). De qualquer forma, acho que é interessante saber **porque** surgem os conflitos, dê uma lida em https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts - sabendo porque eles surgem, fica mais fácil evitar (nem sempre é possível, claro, mas pelo menos vc sabe porque aconteceu). Pela imagem que vc colocou é meio difícil saber, mas *acho* que é porque essas linhas devem ter alguns espaços em branco ou TABs em um branch e no master não (ou vice-versa), ou algo do tipo...

Comment: São conflitos difíceis de evitar, são muitas pessoas trabalhando na mesma coisa, mas eu sei resolver de boa, o problema é justamente essas tags que são adicionadas. E eu acho que é o eclipse por que se lá na view de compare eu uso o text editor no lugar do default, ele salva normalmente sem problema. Mas é um trabalho a mais que eu gostaria de evitar.

Comment: Não é o eclipse, se rodar o git na linha de comando e tiver conflito, ele também adiciona essas marcações. Talvez o problema seja outro (alguém tem uma config de auto-format no eclipse que remove espaços das linhas vazias e acaba criando o conflito, por exemplo - sei lá, é o que me veio à cabeça, podem ser tantas coisas, e só com as informações da pergunta é difícil adivinhar). De qualquer forma, se tem muitas pessoas fazendo **a mesma coisa**, aí é outro problema, e não é o git que vai resolver... :-)

Comment: se não é o eclipse, por que ao utilizar um editor diferente na compare viw, o conflito é resolvido sem problemas?

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que se existir conflito, é o git que adiciona essas marcações (ele que coloca os caracteres `>>>` no arquivo). Agora, se o conflito só ocorre quando usa o Eclipse, aí é outra história, e como eu já disse, só com as informações da pergunta, fica difícil adivinhar (tem que ver o que cada um está fazendo, pode ser a questão do auto-format que mencionei anteriormente, ou algum outro detalhe que me escapa agora...)

Comment: editei a pergunta um pouco, quais informações adicionais você precisa? vc utiliza o eclipse?

Comment: Eu uso Eclipse às vezes, mas quando vou usar o git, sempre vou na linha de comando, então nunca tive esse problema que vc relatou. Desculpe não poder ajudar mais...

Answer (score 0):

tem que da uma estudada no flow do git. o conflito acontece por que a branch q vc esta tentando fazer merge esta um ou mais commits atrás da que vc esta trabalhando.
segue um mini tutorial de como resolver conflitos:

Fazer merge do branch master com o style
Vamos voltar para o branch style e fazer um merge dele com um novo master.

EXECUTE:

```
git checkout style
git merge master
```

RESULTADO:

```
$ git checkout style
Switched to branch 'style'
$ git merge master
Auto-merging lib/hello.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/hello.html
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Se você abrir o lib/hello.html você verá:

```
ARQUIVO: LIB/HELLO.HTML
<!-- Author: Alexander Shvets (alex@githowto.com) -->
<html>
  <head>
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="style.css" />
=======
    <!-- no style -->
>>>>>>> master
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello,World! Life is great!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

A primeira seção e a versão do branch atual (style) head. A segunda seção é a versão do branch master.

02Resolução do conflito
Você precisa resolver o conflito manualmente. Faça mudanças no lib/hello.html para alcançar o seguinte resultado.

ARQUIVO: LIB/HELLO.HTML

```
<!-- Author: Alexander Shvets (alex@githowto.com) -->
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, World! Life is great!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

03Faça o commit de uma resolução de conflito
EXECUTE:

```
git add lib/hello.html
git commit -m "Merged master fixed conflict."
```

RESULTADO:

```
$ git add lib/hello.html
$ git commit -m "Merged master fixed conflict."
Recorded resolution for 'lib/hello.html'.
[style 645c4e6] Merged master fixed conflict.
```

Caso queira saber mais da uma lida no git how to no link a seguir

https://githowto.com/

Comment: Amigo, eu agradeço a resposta, mas eu gostaria de poder resolver pela ferramenta do eclipse mesmo e não pela linha de comando. O problema não é como resolver conflitos, mas por que ao resolvê-los usando o merge tool do eclipse, essas tags continuam presentes.

Comment: as tags sempre aparecerão quando houver conflito. Isso é uma proteção do git para evitar vc perder cod ou implementar coisas quebradas no seu update ou ate mesmo para evitar problemas quando 2 pessoas mexerem no mesmo bloco de código.

Comment: conflitos sao frequentes. acredito que quando vc precise realizar uma tarefa a primeira coisa q vc faz é puxar uma branch do projeto master. depois executa a tarefa. Testa ela e se ok faz o merge com a master e encerra a branch da tarefa.

Comment: sim, a gente sempre resolve, até dei uma editada na pergunta, o problema é que ao utilizar o eclipse eu me deparo com esse problema, quando resolvo de outras formas vai sem problemas

Comment: as vezes vc ta fazendo errado. me desculpé nao poder ajudar com o eclipse pois no git trabalho tudo em linha d comando.